# How Can I List Categories by Date?

Tags: taxonomy, categories

This question isn't specifically about categories, but any taxonomy. I registered a taxonomy called `issue`. I want to list these `issue`s by year. I'm currently using the function:

```
wp_list_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'issue') );
```

I'm not sure how I could output these in a way that would let me view all 'issues' for a given year. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: Probably your question is duplicate of one I answered just yesterday, see [Q50064](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50064/count-posts-for-each-taxonomy-term-for-each-month?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to show list of posts assigned to given category and from given year?

Comment: I want to have a url like site.com/archive/2012, but instead of showing posts from 2012 I want to ti show 'issues' from 2012. Then each of those could be clicked to go to the term's URL of the form site.com/issues/102. Maybe I shouldn't have brought the custom taxonomy into the mix. I'm assuming I could be asking the same question of categories. How could I display the combined categories of the posts in a given year? Since categories themeselves don't have a publish date i'm not sure how to proceed.